# Anonymous types in Spring.Net

Tags: spring.net, anonymous-types

Is there any way to set an object of an anonymous type through Spring.Net?. Really, I've two questions:

- Through ExpressionEvaluator (that's what I want to know principally)
- Through IOC

The object I want to create is like the following:
new { reference = "formid" }

Thanks a lot